# htacess using https in the port

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with forcing HTTPS. I have a GoDaddy Linux Hosting with cPanel.

I have a node app running on the port 8080 so to redirect my domain to that port where my app is running, I use this `.htaccess` code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
```

That works well but I want to force HTTPS redirecting the HTTP domain to HTTPS.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]
```

If I do that I get an Internal Server Error.

What can I do?

Comment: Is there anything in the Apache2 logfile, which gives you a hint?

Comment: You can't have HTTP and HTTPS on the same _port_. But shouldn't you be redirecting the client (ie. the connection from the client to your server), not the route to your node app (which probably doesn't matter so much)?

Comment: @A.Scherbaum Where can I check that logfile?

Comment: @MrWhite I dont have access to apache to create virtual ports (i think its named like that), to redirect the client to my node app I have to do that